# In Dying Light, where is the outfit that actually says the name and slogan of the game?

Tags: dying-light

Ok, so my friend has an outfit where the front of the shirt has the image from the original game's case on it, and the back just has the slogan (Good night. Good luck.).  Does anyone know where I can find this outfit? I have looked at every search result in google (and that was a lot of results) for everything i tried to google it with, and nothing referenced the outfit i want.

PS4-VERSION ONLY, PLEASE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outfit you speak of is called the Team Dying Light outfit. To get it you need to get the secret nuclear ending which requires:

- The Nuclear Codes underwater in a military container
- The Military Keycard inside a warehouse with Behemoth, in a red container
- The Military Access Card underwater under a soldiers body
- The Nuclear Bomb inside a white truck trailer. To enter, swipe the keycard, then gain access to the computer and trigger the bomb by using the keyboard.

<sub>[(Source)](https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/dyinglight/comments/45wdyw/locations_collectible_outfits_the_following/?client=ms-android-att-us)</sub>

The [Wiki](http://dyinglight.wikia.com/wiki/Outfits) says the same thing for this outfit.